# number pattern detection in multidimensional array in c

Tags: c, algorithm

Lets say I want develop a pattern matching algorithm.

Input file contains **dimensions of 'pattern'** and the **'pattern' matrix** itself.

Next it contains the **dimensions of 'match'** and the **'match' matrix** itself.

The dimension of these matrix theoretically can range to **infinity**.

However, the goal is come with an algorithm that can do this when
**pattern_dimensions < match_dimensions**

To keep it simple lets say match_dimensions_max = **1000000x1000000**
and

the **'match' and 'pattern' matrix** both only contains **0s and 1s**.

Typical simple inputs loaded from a file to the program to paint the picture:

'pattern' Array size : 2 X 2

Contents of 'pattern' array

```
|0|1|
|0|0|
-----
```

'match' Array size: 3 x 5

Contents of 'match' array

```
|0|1|0|1|0|
|0|0|0|0|0|
|1|0|0|0|1|
-----------
```

Here I need to only match 0 zeros from 'pattern' array to 'match' array.

```
|0| |
|0|0|
```

This is what I should match and 1 has no significance to positive match.
If you match it you will see it has four matches

```
    2x|0|1|       
      |0|0|
    and
    2x|0|0|
      |0|0|
```

What would be an efficient algorithm to check this?
for this 'pattern' and 'match' array my output should be 4

Comment: What are the values that can be in the match array [and pattern array]? You're only showing 0/1. Is the data boolean? Or, can a match cell have (e.g.) 0,1,2,3,4,5,...,1000? What type are you using for the cell (e.g. `char`, `int`, etc.)? What are the limits on array dimensions? The pattern array is 2x2. How large can it be? More importantly, what is the limit for the match array? Currently, it is 3x5 but what is maximum/typical? Could it have a row length (number of columns) of 1000000? Row values are store sequentially (most efficient). Please edit your _question_ (vs. comments).

Comment: _Inputs are loaded from file should be enough for a real programmer to understand._ So, the data blocks are actually the input files (vs. an abstract array representation). A "real" programmer would have edited the question to provide answers requested, because the question, as is, is incomplete. You wanted "efficient". The array values dictate whether bit masks can be used or not. The array sizes dictate whether a more efficient algorithm for large arrays outweighs the added complexity and setup time. I asked about type. If the values could be 1,000,000,000,000 then we'd need `long long`

Comment: As I said, you only showed 0/1. If that were the case for the match array, simple masking operations would work. They would be 64x faster. This is a trivial convolution kernel problem. If the match array were 1000000x1000000 then caching issues would be a problem.

Comment: It's _your_ code, not mine. You need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes, you are lacking the code you have tried.  See the link in the last comment by @CraigEstey, about how to write a minimal reproducible example, and post some code and what you have tried, and explain on it what is the expected result and what is not working (and why it isn't working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "headers/main.h"

int search_arctic_find_match(char **search_image,int search_row,int search_col,
               char **arctic_image,int arctic_row,int arctic_col){
    
    assert(
        search_image != NULL      &&       \
        arctic_image != NULL      &&       \
        search_row < arctic_row   &&       \
        search_col < arctic_col            \
    );

    /* A VARIABLE THAT KEEPS COUNT OF NUMBER OF MATCHES */
    int count = 0;

    /* THESE TWO LOOPS TRAVERSES MATCHABLE BLOCKS OF ARCTIC IMAGE */
    for(int i=0;i+search_row-1<arctic_row;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j+search_col-1<arctic_col;j++) {

            /* SEARCH ROW AND COLUMN INDEX ARE USED TO ITERATE SEARCH IMAGE */
            int search_row_idx = 0;
            int search_col_idx = 0;

            /* FLAG THAT DEFAULTS AT MATCHED AND EQUALS NOT_MATCHED WHEN A DISCREPANCY IS FOUND */
            int flag = MATCHED;

            
            for(int m = i;m < i+search_row;m++) {
                for(int n=j;n< j+search_col;n++) {

                    if(search_image[search_row_idx][search_col_idx]=='0' && arctic_image[m][n]!=search_image[search_row_idx][search_col_idx]) { 
                        /* IF THE CONDITION IS SATISFIED THEN SET THE FLAG = NOT_MATCHED */
                        flag = NOT_MATCHED;
                        /* AT NOT MATCHED BREAK THE LOOP. NO NEED TO CHECK FURTHER */
                        break;
                    }

                    /* INCREMENT SEARCH COLUMN INDEX */ 
                    search_col_idx++;
                }
                /* RESET SEARCH COLUMN INDEX TO 0 */    
                search_col_idx=0;
                /* INCREMENT SEARCH ROW INDEX */
                search_row_idx++;
            }
            /* RESET SEARCH ROW INDEX TO 0 */
            search_row_idx=0;
            /* IF FLAG UNCHANGED INCREMENT COUNT  */
            if(flag==MATCHED) {
                count++;
            }       
        }   
    }
    /* RETURNS NUMBER OF MATCHES  */        
    return count;   
}
```

Comment: I will take this as answer unless someone else has a better solution